# An algorithm for setting one server as the master among several?

Tags: c#, algorithm, master-slave

Wondering if anyone out there has any advice or examples on a good algorithm for guaranteeing one and only one server be set as the master among several that start up at the same time?

What I have come up with is the following, but the snag is with the last question below:

1. On startup a small service runs that gets host name, and writes
   it to a file on a shared network drive.
2. The machine that comes
   up last will be the the winner and therefore be set as the master.
3. If any machine goes down and comes up again, it will be the
   master.
4. But what happens if the master goes down and doesn't
   come back up?

Or is this all bad to begin with? Is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: Why would you change the master machine because *another* machine goes down?  (3) seems curious.  Also, how do the machines  know which is the master and what are the machines trying to do?  You might be able to find a replication or distributed processing library that handles this for you.

Comment: it's distributed, any ONE and only one machine can be the master because there are tasks that can only be done by one machine and the others don;t need to know, they only need to know that they are NOT the master.

Comment: In step (3), how do you tell the current master that it is no longer the master?  In step (1), how do the machines know what is the last one to come up?  If not all the machines come up, how long can you live without a master?

Comment: Why is the last one chosen as master? why not choose the first one?

Comment: The question is incomplete. What are the responsibilities of the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various solutions to this problem.  If you are assuming that a shared file system is always available, then that simplifies the problem.

- Each time a computer comes up, it checks the "master" file on the shared system.
- If none is there, it creates the master file and writes its name to it.
- If one is there, it checks to see if the master hostname is up.  If the master hostname is up, it then does nothing.
- If the master hostname is not up, it writes its name to the master file and it is now the master.
- Before any machine does any "master" operation, it checks the shared hostname to be sure it is the master.

This is not a fool-proof solution, because it relies on the file system to control access to the file (two computers coming up my both try to write to the file at the same time).  However, because the master file should only have one hostname in it, the final step should guarantee that only one computer really thinks its the master.

The problem is a bit harder without the assumption of an up-all-the-time shared file system.

Comment: It's also a little harder when the Master is supposed to initiate actions. How do you detect failure?

Comment: @HenkHolterman . . . Good point.  I read the passive voice in "there are tasks that can only be done by one machine" and I interpreted that (wrongly) as the machine is *responding* to tasks, rather than initiating them.  The question of detecting failure, I assume, is based on reading the master file on the shared file system and checking to see if the master is there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe is called "leader election". One possible solution is called raft-algorithm.
There's a c# implementation on github: https://github.com/hhblaze/Raft.Net

There's also https://dotnet.github.io/dotNext/#dotnextnetcluster which has implemenrations for .net core